# How to Use Fillable Checkboxes from Hyperref with Lists

Tags: hyperref, lists, enumitem

I would like to create a fillable PDF form with a list of items that each have a checkbox to its left.

It would look similar to this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}[label = $\square$ \arabic*:]
\item Some item 1
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\arabic*)]
    \item Some subitem 
    \end{enumerate}
\item Some item 2
\item Some item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

The fundamental difference is instead of $square$, each list item would have a fillable checkbox from hyperref that could be filled in.

An additional problem I encountered in trying to solve this was that each checkbox must have a unique name for it to be independent of other checkboxes. In other words, if a checkbox has the same name as another in a PDF, when one is selected/unselected the other is as well.

What would be the most effective and concise way of approaching this?

Comment: Welcome! The most effective and concise way? Read section 6 of the `hyperref` manual? And make sure that everyone who will use the form uses Adobe Reader. This essentially now means they all need OS X or Windows. (Text fields tend to work for GNU/Linux users, though. But probably not fancy stuff like check boxes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checkbox names, in this case, are given by test1, test2 and test3.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}[label = {\CheckBox[name=test\theenumi]{}} \arabic*:]
\item Some item 1
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\arabic*)]
    \item Some subitem 
    \end{enumerate}
\item Some item 2
\item Some item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great idea: to include the `\theenumi` in the name... A big kudo !